# How to log a request body (via middleware) without buffering?

Tags: go

Suppose I had this simple server (error handling omitted for the sake of brevity):

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "The request is: %s", string(b))
}
```

I need to add a simple middleware that reads the body of the request and logs it. I already have this working solution:

```
func requestLogger(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        pr, pw := io.Pipe()
        tee := io.TeeReader(r.Body, pw)
        r.Body = pr
        go func() {
            body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(tee)
            defer pw.Close()
            log.Printf("This is the logged request: %s", string(body))
        }()
        next(w, r)
    }
}
```

I arrived intuitively to this solution by trial and error, so I am unsure if this is going to work in all cases. These are my questions regarding my own solution:

1. **Why do I have to manually close the `Pipe`?** Doesn't `ioutil.ReadAll()` closes it when it encounters EOF on r.Body.
2. **Why is this not blocking?** There is a circular reference because `TeeReader` reads from the same same source (r.Body) to which it writes via the Pipe (r.Body = pr). According to the documentation, Write to the PipeWriter blocks until it has satisfied one or more Reads, and in the case of TeeReader, the write must complete before the read completes.

Answer (score 1):

> Doesn't ioutil.ReadAll() closes it when it encounters EOF?

---

> [Package ioutil](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/)
>
> [func ReadAll](https://golang.org/pkg/io/ioutil/#ReadAll)
>
> ```
> func ReadAll(r io.Reader) ([]byte, error)
> ```
>
> ReadAll reads from r until an error or EOF and returns the data it
>   read.

---

That is not the documented behavior. Also, `io.Reader` is not an `io.ReadCloser`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. This part of the documentation is what confused me: "The Server will close the request body. The ServeHTTP Handler does not need to."